# How do I upgrade from JavaVM 32bit to JavaVM64bit

Tags: java, jvm, phpstorm

I have a 64bit operating system with phpStorm 9.0.2 installed.
I get out of memory errors and it seems like JVM32bit might not help the cause.

How can I upgrade my JVM32bit version to JVM64bit?
Is it just as simple as downloading a 64bit version and installing it or are there any other extra steps to take to do this correctly?

OS Win 7 64bit

Comment: 32 bit OS or 64 bit? Right click on my computer and choose properties and it should be mentioned there under **System** as System type.

Comment: Uninstall Java and install the 64 bit version. Have you tried it? Any issues?

Comment: Yeah, no I have not, I wanted to make sure I dont miss anything else besides uninstalling JVM32.

Comment: See this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3xt4qOZuoQ , it describes how to upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run PhpStorm even if you have no Java installed on your computer as **on Windows it comes bundled with own 32-bit JRE** which will be used by default ignoring your system-wide Java (if you have one).

That's why "uninstall 32-bit Java and just install 64-bit one instead" is not enough (as in some cases you simply have no system-wide Java installed on your computer).

---

1. Download and install **64-bit JDK** (yes, it has to be JDK and not just JRE)
2. Create `IDEA_JDK_64` environment variable and point it to **JDK root folder**. For example:

   [image]
3. Use 64-bit PhpStorm's executable (`PhpStorm64.exe`) instead of 32-bit (`PhpStorm.exe`).

The above works just fine for me.

If anything -- please refer to [official support article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827547-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under).

Comment: Okay, that seems simple enough. Will be in touch. Thanks.